# Trying to run Selenium test script with smart card authentication

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm trying to run my Selenium scripts to test our software capabilities. Our modules are web-based and they require smart card authentication in order for me to access them. I have Selenium launch Firefox a specific URL, which resides behind a proxy. Once the browser launches, I will get prompted to enter my card pin. Once I enter my pin, my Selenium script will terminate instantly.

The smart card pin prompt doesn't have any reference for me to tell Selenium what to look for (no xpath, CSS selector, class id, etc.). I can't even inspect it's elements

Is there a way to run Selenium scripts behind a proxy?

I'm using Python for my language and OpenAM, which configures our smart card authentication.

Comment: I guess the smartcard pop-up is created by the browser (or Windows) and so isn't part of the web page? Is there any way you can run these tests from a machine on the other side of the proxy rather than trying to run them through the proxy? That sounds like it's never going to work satisfactorily.

Comment: Elvir Muslic - I think I posted my question the wrong way. I know how to run Selenium test scripts. I guess my question should be, how do I somehow bypass the smart card authentication part so that my Selenium sessions don't terminate?

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Card authentication is generated by Windows, therefore you won't be able to use Selenium for authentication.

I was able to use pywinauto to automate the Smart Card authentication.
It was tricky because the driver.get() call has a lock on the process until the authentication is completed.
I had to use multiprocessing to run Selenium and pywinauto as separate processes.